# Некорректный шрифт при загрузке из файла в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, шрифты

Загружаю шрифт в программу посредством

```
GetNonCachedFontFamilies(MainPath).FirstOrDefault();
```

**Метод GetNonCachedFontFamilies**

```
public static IEnumerable<FontFamily> GetNonCachedFontFamilies(string location)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty("location"))
        throw new ArgumentException("Must provide a location", "location");

    DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(location);
    if (directoryInfo.Exists)
    {
        FileInfo[] fileInfos = directoryInfo.GetFiles("*.?tf");
        foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in fileInfos)
            yield return CreateFontFamily(fileInfo.FullName);
    }
    else
    {
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(location);
        if (fileInfo.Exists)
            yield return CreateFontFamily(location);
    }
}
```

**Метод CreateFontFamily**

```
private static FontFamily CreateFontFamily(string path)
{
    if (!Uri.TryCreate(path, UriKind.Absolute, out Uri uri))
        throw new ArgumentException("Must provide a valid location", "path");

    return new FontFamily(uri, string.Empty);
}
```

Шрифт программа находит и загружает, с этим проблем нет. Только отображается шрифт не правильно. Это должен быть рукописный кириллический шрифт, а похож на Microsoft Sans Serif/Calibri (т.е. не рукописный). Что я не так делаю?
*Если что, текст отображаю посредством TextBlock, который динамически создаётся из кода. Прошу без xaml.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы неправильно используете функцию `new FontFamily(uri, string.Empty)`, надо обязательно использовать имя шрифта. Ниже рабочий код.

```
public static IEnumerable<FontFamily> GetNonCachedFontFamilies(string location)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty("location"))
        throw new ArgumentException("Must provide a location", "location");

    DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(location);
    if (directoryInfo.Exists)
    {
        FileInfo[] fileInfos = directoryInfo.GetFiles("*.?tf");
        foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in fileInfos)
            yield return CreateFontFamily(fileInfo.DirectoryName, fileInfo.Name);
    }
    else
    {
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(location);
        if (fileInfo.Exists)
            yield return CreateFontFamily(fileInfo.DirectoryName, fileInfo.Name);
    }
}

private static FontFamily CreateFontFamily(string path, string filename)
{
    if (!Uri.TryCreate(path + "\\" + filename, UriKind.Absolute, out Uri uri))
        throw new ArgumentException("Must provide a valid location", "path");

    GlyphTypeface glyphTypeface = new GlyphTypeface(uri);
    return new FontFamily(path + "\\#" + glyphTypeface.FamilyNames.FirstOrDefault().Value);
}
```